# SSMS - Seeking help writing a select statement to return duplicates in SQL [Example included]

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am trying to implement validation to check whether the same FX rate has been entered in reverse order for the same date. Users would populate a spreadsheet consisting of five columns:

- Date
- From Currency
- To Currency
- Rate
- Multiply/Divide

The user would add data into a spreadsheet to import through the system, below is a mock example of how the data would look in the table in the database:

[image]

I have the structure of the validation in place, I am just wondering how I would write a select statement in order to return all rows which:

- Have **both directions for the same date**, as shown in the first two rows in the image above^. **USD & GBP both have Multiply (M) and Divide (D) for the 01/02/2023**, therefore I would like to return these rows as to fail the validation, none of the other rows in the example should be returned as they are valid.

**I thought I'd include a script to create the table shown in the image above which includes the exact data shown. I am hoping to return the first two rows from the table above**

```
CREATE TABLE [tblFXRates](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [FromCurrency] [nvarchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [ToCurrency] [nvarchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [Rate] [decimal](19, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Divide/Multiply] [nvarchar](1) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [tblFXRates] ON 
GO
INSERT [tblFXRates] ([ID], [Date], [FromCurrency], [ToCurrency], [Rate], [Divide/Multiply]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2023-02-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'USD', N'GBP', CAST(1.30 AS Decimal(19, 2)), N'M')
GO
INSERT [tblFXRates] ([ID], [Date], [FromCurrency], [ToCurrency], [Rate], [Divide/Multiply]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2023-02-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'GBP', N'USD', CAST(1.30 AS Decimal(19, 2)), N'D')
GO
INSERT [tblFXRates] ([ID], [Date], [FromCurrency], [ToCurrency], [Rate], [Divide/Multiply]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2023-02-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'GBP', N'EUR', CAST(1.11 AS Decimal(19, 2)), N'M')
GO
INSERT [tblFXRates] ([ID], [Date], [FromCurrency], [ToCurrency], [Rate], [Divide/Multiply]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2023-02-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'GBP', N'GBP', CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(19, 2)), N'M')
GO
INSERT [tblFXRates] ([ID], [Date], [FromCurrency], [ToCurrency], [Rate], [Divide/Multiply]) VALUES (5, CAST(N'2023-02-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'GBP', N'GBP', CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(19, 2)), N'D')
GO
INSERT [tblFXRates] ([ID], [Date], [FromCurrency], [ToCurrency], [Rate], [Divide/Multiply]) VALUES (6, CAST(N'2023-02-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'USD', N'USD', CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(19, 2)), N'M')
GO
INSERT [tblFXRates] ([ID], [Date], [FromCurrency], [ToCurrency], [Rate], [Divide/Multiply]) VALUES (7, CAST(N'2023-02-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'USD', N'USD', CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(19, 2)), N'D')
GO
INSERT [tblFXRates] ([ID], [Date], [FromCurrency], [ToCurrency], [Rate], [Divide/Multiply]) VALUES (8, CAST(N'2023-02-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'EUR', N'GBP', CAST(0.90 AS Decimal(19, 2)), N'M')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [tblFXRates] OFF
GO
```

Edit:

[image]

Comment: And what happens when USD/BGP rows both have just M or D? The rate value for both rows is not used to determine duplicate? And why do you have multiple USD/USD rows? That makes no sense at all but seems to qualify as duplicate.

Comment: If for example USD/GBP just have M or D then thats fine as we're able to import both directions, however I am trying to stop the user entering two directions at once incase the rates don't match. I thought I'd include that data to be clear that if it was entered like that it shouldn't be included in this select statement as I have different validation which ensures that an exception is thrown if the scenarios you state above happen. @SMor

Comment: it doesnt make sense to have FX like N'GBP', N'GBP'

Comment: @asi that's the way the data comes in, so don't have much control over that. It doesn't cause any problems since the rate of course just gets entered as 1

Comment: Then your logic seems to be a small refinement of that in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64463325/sql-server-validation-against-duplicate-values-in-reverse-in-two-columns-exam).

Comment: And if you are only concerned about dates, then why do you use datetime for that column? Don't encourage the probability of more problems with carelessly chosen datatypes.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter? Why do you keep using images of data? Do you expect an image of a query?

Answer (score 0):

this will do:

assumig we want only those with different FromCurrency & ToCurrency, but of course you can change this.

```
SELECT 
    tbl1.*
FROM 
    test.tblfxrates tbl1
inner join
    test.tblfxrates tbl2 on tbl2.FromCurrency = tbl1.ToCurrency and tbl2.ToCurrency = tbl1.FromCurrency and tbl1.FromCurrency <> tbl1.ToCurrency and tbl1.Date = tbl2.Date
where
    tbl1.DivideMultiply <> tbl2.DivideMultiply
order by 
    tbl1.ID
```

it will return the first 2 lines

Comment: added and tbl1.Date = tbl2.Date

Comment: Nearly there, I have more data in my local base and I applied your script and ran it and it did indeed return those two rows, however it also returned two extra rows that shouldn't be included, I have updated the post and attached a new image of the extra rows returned. It appears that it is not taking the Divide Multiply column into account correctly. Since both of these values are M we don't want to throw an error on these as they are valid since they're both multiplying/M. @asi

Comment: doesn't make sense. should happen only if you disable the where condition. you better try double check or provide more sample data.

unless, you have got some hidden whitespace in Divide Multiply column that causes them not to be equals